# Node setup for ghostnet of tezos

Tags: tezos-client

I'm setting up the RPC node for Ghostnet of tezos and I'm following https://opentezos.com/deploy-a-node/installation#set-up-using-ppa-with-tezos-packages-from-serokell this tutorial and my node started syncing but when I pasted the blockhash which I got from my logs file it's not appearing on ghostnet explorer but appearing on mainnet explorer why it's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the instructions in the link you've given are slightly incorrect.

There is nothing wrong with the first command:

```
tezos-node config init --data-dir ~/tezos-ghostnet --network=ghostnet --history-mode=full
```

As explained there the `--network=ghostnet`, if specified, configures the node to run on it (as you want), however that command also picks a non-default data directory for the node (`--data-dir ~/tezos-ghostnet`).

The issue is with the next command:

```
tezos-node run --rpc-addr 127.0.0.1:8732 --log-output tezos.log
```

because here no `--data-dir` is given, so the default one is used and not the one you've just set up.

Stopping that and instead running:

```
tezos-node run --rpc-addr 127.0.0.1:8732 --log-output tezos.log --data-dir ~/tezos-ghostnet
```

should work for you.

However if you're using `tezos-packaging` for Ubuntu, I'd recommend following [the quick setup there](https://github.com/serokell/tezos-packaging#set-up-a-node-andor-baking-on-ubuntu) which has a step-by-step utility that will guide you.
In your case (since you've added the PPA already) running these two commands is enough:

```
sudo apt-get install -y tezos-baking
tezos-setup-wizard
```

Comment: Now it's syncing data for ghostnet but there's an issue it has synced some block and I stopped the syncing and after 3 hrs I've started again syncing but it's not syncing

Comment: Maybe the node data got corrupted, it's hard to say.

Comment: Can you see any error in the logs?